# how to solve 500 internal server error mod_wsgi apache "importerror: No Module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, vps

I have been trying to solve this error but I am not been able to solve, totally frustrated because I have tried every single answer on these related question , any help would be appreciated.

My configuration of VPS server

```
Ubuntu 18.04
django 2.2.5
apache 2.4.49
python 3.6(virtualenv)
libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

My folder structure is:

```
/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/venv (virtualenv folder)
    bin
    include
    lib

/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project
    |- manage.py
    static
    venv
    prediction_project
        |__init__.py
        |settings.py
        |urls.py
        |wsgi.py
```

**000-default.conf file code**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess prediction_project python-path=/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project python-home=/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup prediction_project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project/wsgi.py

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite_error.log
   LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

my wsgi.py file code
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project')

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/venv/lib/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'prediction_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My server logs

```
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003624 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]  mod_wsgi (pid=82169): Target WSGI script '/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003722 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]  mod_wsgi (pid=82169): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003823 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003844 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]  File "/var/www/dataforze/prediction_project/prediction_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003849 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Mar 18 17:29:01.003864 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 82169:tid 140431942575872]  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: have you installed django inside your venv?

Comment: @dirkgroten yes i have installed everything

Comment: are you sure about the locations? your venv is **inside** your prediction_project folder according to you, but when you show your prediction_project folder (with manage.py) I don't see venv. Also there's no reason to change your sys.path inside wsgi.py. Remove that.

Comment: yes I am damn sure about the locations wait letme add there

Comment: so after `cd /var/www/dataforze/prediction_project`, if you do `./venv/bin/python -m django --version`, it returns the version? (don't activate your venv when you check this)

Comment: @dirkgroten it gives -bash:  Permission denied although i have given chmod 777 to the this folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209872/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-dirkgroten).